# Flutter textfield crash with chinese input method

Tags: forms, input, flutter

I run my flutter app in IOS device (not simlulator).
Select some characters in Chinese keyboard in the first textfield, then select the second textfield without choosing a Chinese character from the prediction.
Please help to solve this issue.
Here is the example image:
[image]

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b12029b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a6c4735 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b1200f5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0666e3 -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 163
4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011497fb5a -[UIKeyboardImpl hasMarkedText] + 143
5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011496f3a8 __43-[UIKeyboardImpl generateAutofillCandidate]_block_invoke + 51
6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001149da9bf -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:] + 169
7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001149d91ae -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 374
8   UIKitCore  <…>
Lost connection to device.
```